# Level set of $f(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f:\ \mathbb R^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be a smooth function and $a$ is a regular value of $f$.

Show that the level set $f^{-1}(a)$ define a curve.

Here is my attempt. Let $(x,y)\in f^{-1}(a)$, then $f(x,y)=a$. My idea is to use the Inverse function theorem. So I consider a map $g:\ \mathbb R^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R^2$ where $g(x,y)=\big(f(x,y),0\big)$. Since $(x,y)$ is regular point of $f$, it’s also regular point of $g$. So, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $(x,y)$ and a neighborhood V of $g(x,y)$ such that $U,V$ diffeomorphic through the map $g\Big|_U$. So I let $$U=g^{-1}(a)=f^{-1}(a)$$
and this implies $f^{-1}(a)$ diffeomorphic to $V$. But $V$ is of 1-dimension since $$V\subset g(\mathbb R^2)\subset\mathbb R\times\{0\}$$.

Is my proof correct ? May you give me a help with this problem ? Thanks

Comment: You don't have $U = f^{-1} (A)$, but implicit value theorem could give you something like $f(x, y(x)) = a$ but only locally, with this you could show that $f^{-1}(a)$ is a one dimensional line fiber bundle, which would give you the answer

Comment: is there any other way that doesn’t need the Implicit value theorem ?

Comment: Implicit mapping theorem is your friend here. Inverse function theorem is something else entirely.

Comment: yeah, just a problem with it that my book didn’t add the Implicit value theorem into its lecture